# Using Ipython Notebook with DataNitro

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook, datanitro

I extensively use Ipython and its notebook.   I also use DataNitro to get python functionality in Excel.   Was wondering anybody has been able to use Ipython Notebook with the python instance running in DataNitro?    This would make debugging and development much easier.

DataNitro can already open a Ipython Shell, but I cant figure out if I link an Ipython notebook to this shell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, DataNitro doesn't support IPython Notebook integration. Try using [pdb](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/pdb.html) for debugging in the IPython shell.

Source: I'm one of the DataNitro developers.